# Why am I getting Illegal Token when outputting JavaScript from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to output Google Translate code from PHP (wordpress plugin) to the page and it is giving me Illegal Token errors even though when I paste the exact same line of code directly into the console and run it, it works.

Here is my PHP:

```
    function AddTranslateSidebar(){
  echo "<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      gt = escape('<div id=\"google_translate_element\"></div><script type=\"text/javascript\">function googleTranslateElementInit() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: \"en\", layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, \"google_translate_element\");}</script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit\"></script>');
      jQuery('#sidebar').prepend(unescape(gt));
    });
  </script>";
}
```

That code outputs the following into the page as HTML/JavaScript:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      gt = escape('<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">function googleTranslateElementInit() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: "en", layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, "google_translate_element");}</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>');
      jQuery('#sidebar').prepend(unescape(gt));
    });
  </script>
```

Which causes the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

On the gt = escape( ... ); line.

However, if I copy that code directly from the HTML source using the inspector and then paste it into the console and run it, it works and the translate dropdown shows up.

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the unescaped string being returned properly? Have you pasted into jslint?

Comment: why escape/unescape? `gt='blahblahblah'; .prepend(gt)` would do just as well.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes the unescaped string is coming back properly - as I said I copied the output straight from the HTML output by PHP and pasted it into the console and it ran perfectly fine. You can see it here: http://www.georgiancollege.ca/internationaldev/current-students/

Comment: @MarcB you're correct - the escape does nothing - I originally had it without it and got the exact same results - I only added it to see if it was an escaping issue - but with or without I get the exact same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence of characters `</script>` always means to end the current script block.  My suspicion is that this is causing the problem.

You can't include `</script>` verbatim in a JavaScript string.  Instead you need to break it up and re-concatenate the parts.

E.g. this:

```
"</script>"
```

Should become this:

```
"<" + "/script>"
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this along with appending each element separately instead of one big string of elements. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Change `gt = escape('...')` to just `gt = '...'`

Comment: That doesn't work either - I added the escape in cause PHP was causing some issue - it's the exact same with or without escape...